# .htaccess Rewrite for PDFs from root to subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to automatically redirect all .PDF and .pdf files from the website root to a subdirectory called docs.

Note that there aren't any actual PDFs on the website root, which is why I'm trying to use the !-f bit.

This is what I came up with so far, but it isn't working. I would appreciate any help.

```
# redirect PDF files requested on the root '/' to /docs/<filename>.(pdf|PDF)
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.(pdf|PDF))$ /docs/$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/docs%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*\.pdf)$ /docs/$1 [L,NC]
```

The second condition may not be needed, it's there in case a request is made that ends with ".pdf" but the pdf isn't actually there, thus the first condition is true and there's a rewrite loop (resulting in a 500 server error).